# Using Two Assemblies One with Preprocessor Define and One Without

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my C# solution I have an assembly project called A.Foo that B-PUBLIC.EXE depends on. It uses the namespace A.Foo.

Also in my solution I have a duplicate of that assembly project (same source files) called A.FooPrivate that B-PRIVATE.EXE depends on. It also uses the namespace A.Foo.

The private version uses a preprocessor define 'PRIVATE' to include some private definitions that are not available in the public version.

In the EXEs I have:

using A.Foo;

When I compile I get an error from B-PRIVATE.EXE "the type 'Bar' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly A.Foo". This is right, I don't have assembly A.Foo referenced, instead I have A.FooPrivate referenced that exposes the same namespace with the same data types as A.Foo.

Why am I getting this error?

Then I changed the output name of A.FooPrivate to A.Foo and output it to a different folder 'Debug-Private' instead of 'Debug'. Now it has the same name as the public version A.Foo.dll but is in a different folder.

The previous problem goes away however I now have a new problem, when I build my entire solution Debug/A.Foo.dll and Debug-Private/A.Foo.dll are identical.

Why are they the same? One uses the preprocessor define PRIVATE and one does not.

As a sanity check if I only build B-PRIVATE.EXE instead of the whole solution then it uses A.FooPrivate which contains the private definitions as expected.

Visual Studio 2017. Thanks!

Comment: Do you maybe have a repo reproducing a solution could help understand the problem?

Comment: Yeah this should be easy to write a small example of the first instance. it would be much easier for us to understand what you are doing

Comment: A description is very unclear. Maybe is Shared project right solution? https://dailydotnettips.com/using-shared-project-across-multiple-applications-in-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
#if PRIVATE
[assembly: Guid("8E360062-8C2B-4312-94E8-6CB27FC810B0")]
#else
[assembly: Guid("bb00e017-fe81-4f7a-8613-4122a97b31b1")]
#endif
```

Now VS sees the two assemblies as different.